# Converting a JSON file to CSV file with multivalue features

Tags: python, json, pandas, csv, machine-learning

I have to do a Machine Learning project and my data set is in the form of JSON files. I have a feature position with 3 values `(x,y,z)`. When I convert the JSON files to CSV files with Python I have the values of feature position in the form of array.

How can I generate from one feature three features `pos_x, pos_y and pos_z` ??

JSON: `"pos":[3838.387671754935,5853.151423739182,1.895]`
CSV: `"pos": "[3838.387671754935,5853.151423739182,1.895]"`

But I must have 3 separated features pos_x : 3838.387671754935, pos_y: 5853.151423739182, pos_z: 1.895

The code I used :

```
import pandas as pd 
import json

data = []

with open('JSONfile.json') as fh:
    for line in fh:
        data.append(json.loads(line))

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
df.to_csv ('csvFile.csv', index = False)
```

Comment: Do you have multiple JSON files all in the same format that you need to combine into one CSV output? (or one CSV file per JSON file?)  Does each JSON file just contain that one entry or is there an array of entries?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Miller](https://miller.readthedocs.io/) (mlr) to produce all kind of different output:

```
mlr --ijson --ocsv cat multivalued.json
```

which will return the following CSV

```
pos.1,pos.2,pos.3
3838.387671754935,5853.151423739182,1.895
```

or for a table formatting

```
+-------------------+-------------------+-------+
| pos.1             | pos.2             | pos.3 |
+-------------------+-------------------+-------+
| 3838.387671754935 | 5853.151423739182 | 1.895 |
+-------------------+-------------------+-------+
```

with this alternate

```
mlr --ijson --opprint --barred cat multivalued.json
```

and if you don't specify output format (CSV, pretty print...) it will use DKVP (key-value pair):

```
pos.1=3838.387671754935,pos.2=5853.151423739182,pos.3=1.895
```

NB: the index is numeric and separator is dot (.1, .2... instead of _a, _b, etc.)